# OpenCL support for OpenCV featuredetector/deskriptor

Tags: opencv, opencl, sift, surf

I recently start experimenting with OpenCv, especially with the featuredetectors (eg. SIFT, SURF ...)
Now i´m starting to look into OpenCL and I wanted to ask if there is OpenCL "support" for these featuredetectors.

While "googleing" the question I found this link [1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ocl/doc/ocl.html) with possible OpenCL accelerated functions. But there are no featuredetectors listed, only the matchers.
On github I found following code [2](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/246ea8f3bdf174a2aad6216c2601e3a93bf75c29/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cpp) which indicates that it is possible to use SURF. 
Does anybody know which fetectors/feskriptors are implemented in OpenCL? (And maybe how to use them)

Greetings Drian

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL does not directly support any feature detectors.

OpenCL is not a framework for image processing, but a low-level API to run algorithm in parallel. Therefore it supports many low level functions, such as vector functions, trigonometric functions and other low level instructions, but no domain specific functions, as detecting features in an image.

OpenCV uses OpenCL to accelerate certain operations by running them on the GPU.

Basically, if you want to use a high level, easy to use library for **image processing**, you use **OpenCV**.

If you want to implement an algorithm for **parallel execution** by yourself on CPUs, GPUs or other accelerators, you use **OpenCL**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if i want to accelerate eg. SURF on a GPU or any other parallel processor I need to try to code it by myself using the opencv functions + selfwritten functions that are implemented in opencl? Or is it possible to "say to opencv´s implemantation of surf use opencl to accelerate yourself"

Comment: @Drian: Corect, you will have to implement the algorithms by yourself. You cannot just "copy&paste" OpenCV source code since the algorithm has to be written for parallel execution. The parallel code is called kernels. These Kernels are written in a subset of the C++ language specification.